# Exclude specific folders with Gulp

Tags: gulp

If I have the following structure, how can I exclude all folders with the format "xx_YY" EXCEPT for "en_US" within `gulp.src`?

```
images/
   |_ en_US/
   |_ en_GB/ (this should be ignored)
   |_ de_DE/ (this should be ignored)
   |_ etc etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
var images = [
    'images/**/*',
    '!images/en_GB/**/*', 
    '!images/de-DE/**/*'
];

gulp.src(images)...
```